# Is not an Integer variable a reference type?

Tags: java, types, reference, void

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int a = 1;
    Integer b = new Integer("1");
    Integer c = a;
    int result = b + a;
    int[] f = new int[1];


    System.out.println(result);
    check(b);
    check1(f);
    Integer K = new Integer(10);
    int J = K.intValue();
    System.out.println(b + " " + f[0] );
    if(b.equals(a)) 
        System.out.println(a);
}

static void check(Integer d)
{
    d = 20;
}

static int[] check1(int[] a)
{
    a[0] = 20;

    return a;
}
```

first I'm curious to use primitive variable and reference variable.

let me know how to show

> `System.out.println(b)`
>
> **output**
>
> 20

array is reference type, and int is primitive type.

and Integer is reference type. but It is not changed from 1 to 2

Comment: The fact that `Integer` is a reference type does not mean that it is passed by reference - in fact, everything is passed by value in Java; including references. (Note: Passing a reference by value is not the same as passing by reference!).

Comment: as you said, means having a difference with refence and value reference.
please let me know how to get output as 20

Comment: In the method `check()` you could do the same trick as you did in `check1()` by using an array - there is no way to modify the `Integer` as you do now in `check()` because Java passes by value, and not by reference.